# Parse json angular request put

Tags: angular, request, put

I have a little probleme with my put request. In my nodejs If the request is successfull, I send a message json to angular like this.

```
res.json({ success: true, message: 'Success'})
```

In angular I create a request  to catch this message after added or modified the object in database. If I add the object I can catch  this message from the nodejs and I can parse this message, but if I want modify one object I can't parse json and I have this message error.

[image]

***Classe.service.ts***

```
updateClasse(room, id) {
   const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/api/classes/update/' + id;
   const obj = { room: room };

   this.http.put(uri, obj).subscribe(
     (res:any)=> {
       this.okReq = res.message;
       return this.okReq;
     });
}
```

***Classe.component.ts***

```
  updateClasse(room) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.service.updateClasse(room, params['id']);
     });
    this.router.navigate(['/classes']);
 }
```

***Classe.html***

```
{{ okReq }}
<form [formGroup]="angForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4">Classe Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="room" #room [(ngModel)] = "classe.room"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button (click)="updateClasse(room.value)" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your response **`type`** as **`any`**

```
 this.http.put(uri, obj).subscribe(
     (res:any)=> {
       console.log(res.message)
});
```

Comment: One question again, how can I put res.message in my wiew?

Comment: you can declare a variable and assign the value to the variable. and then {{myvariable}} in view

Comment: I changed the code but it's not work in my view, I past in service angular the variable who contain the message and in my view I use this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic types to set the type of the returned value from http operations. Let's assume you already have a `MessageResponse` type:

```
interface MessageResponse {
  success: boolean;
  message: string;
}
```

Now you can use this as a generic argument to `.put`:

```
this.http.put<MessageResponse>(uri, obj)
```

Now the `res` is assumed to be of type `MessageResponse` which will allow you to access `res.message` as a string value.

---

By the way I wouldn't use `.subscribe` in your service. Instead, I would use it whenever you need to actually call the http request such as in a component or other service that depends on the response.